# Find the missing number: 321,6; 432,48; 333,81; 432,353; 321,?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Looking for the solution of IQ question below:

> 321 6
>  432 48
>  333 81
>  432 353
>  321 ?

[image]

Comment: [POTENTIAL SPOILER] A pattern for the first three rows: left column cell product multiplied by row index = right column cell. 3*2*1*1 = 6, 4*3*2*2 = 48, 3*3*3*3 = 81. But then for the fourth row, 4*3*2*4 = 96 != 353. :/ Also, 353 is a prime number.

Comment: @SpiritFryer Thanks for your comment. Agree with you that the first three rows had the same pattern but the forth is totally out of pattern. Maybe there are plus and minus to get 353 as it a prime number.

Comment: Where is the image from?

Comment: Just for clarity. Are you asking for the *solution* of the question, or asking *how one goes about to solve* such a question? Your first line is slightly confusing here and might require an edit...

Comment: @BmyGuest Thanks for the clarification. I am looking for helps to solve it.

Comment: This question has been asked here as well https://www.question.com/how-to-solve-this-iq-question-1088220.html

Comment: @AJ: Both asked around the same time by a new user on each site ;)

Comment: @dpwilson: That is called distributed computing ;)

Comment: Maybe the pattern is simply that it repeats itself again and the answer would be 6?

Comment: Also noted the 4^4 + 3^4 + 2^4 = 353

Comment: @AlexChance: But 432 yields two different values in the second column, so it can't just be a repeat

Comment: @dpwilson you are correct I didn't notice that.

Comment: I had this as an answer until z100 pointed out it was wrong: going off of @Maxqueue's comment, we see that $3^1+2^1+1^1=6$, $3^3+3^3+3^3=81$, and $4^4+3^4+2^4=353$, but $4^2+3^2+2^2=29\neq 48$.

Comment: It's an IQ question, right? Surely an IQ question doesn't require knowledge of primes, cubes, etc. ?!?!

Comment: I was sort of pondering the possibility the right side caused the left side, except that could imply not strictly deterministic from the two 432's unless line number is a factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this slightly "twisted" method?

> (Yielding $276$)
>
>  - basically fudging it with what people have noted in the comments...
>
>  The number on the left has digits
>  $d_nd_{n-1}\cdots d_2d_1$
>  and is in row $r$, starting at $1$
>
>  The number on the right is whichever of $$A=\sum_{i=0}^n{d_i^r}$$  $$B=d_n^rd_{n-1}$$ is smaller after its digits have been reversed.

That would be

> If $x'$ reverses the digits of $x$
>
> ```
> Row  Left     A     B     A'    B'   min(A', B')' = Right
>   1   321     6     6     6     6              6
>   2   432    29    48    92    84             48
>   3   333    81    81    18    18             81
>   4   432   353   768   353   867            353
>   5   321   276   486   672   684            276
> ```

Not really fitting for an "IQ" test though.

Answer (score 5):

Kind of reaching a little here but here goes:

> if index is prime apply following pattern where n is the index and d is the digit:dxdxdxn
> If index is not prime apply following pattern where n is the index and d is the digit:d^n + d^n + d^n
> Therefore the answer would be:
> If index is prime apply following pattern where n is the index and d is the digit:dxdxdxn

Therefore the answer is:

> 30

Because of the fact that:

> the index is 5 which is prime so 3x2x1x5=30

Comment: The number 1 isn't prime.

Comment: @dpwilson Still works, since $3^1+2^1+1^1=6$. :)

Comment: @dpwilson: Yes, but 1·2·3·1 and 1¹ + 2¹ + 3¹ are both six.

Comment: Ha, whoops. My bad.

Comment: I hope there is a cleaner solution (I don't like the change of pattern with prime numbers)

Comment: Agree with @Lord of dark comment. There exist many ways using two different relative simple formulas to achieve those 4 pairs. Row number really seems to be significant and also the sum of 353 of 4th powers. But maybe it is a false flag.

Answer (score 3):

The answer can also be

> 276

because you can get right hand side choosing

> $$\max \left \{  nabc, a^n+b^n+c^n\right \} $$where $n$ is number of the row starts from $1$

Answer (score -1):

The answer is

> 6

Reasoning

> Its the same as the first line (321->6). Everything else is a red herring.

Comment: BTW, this was tried already, and it isn't the answer. Why aren't the 432 the same then?

Comment: what about 2nd and 4th line?